# List modification fails

Tags: python, string, list

This piece of code in Python should modify dates in a list to a format dd.mm.yyyy. Somehow I get the same list at the end of the day.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

```
dates_list_modified = ['7.2.2009', '03.08.2023', '18.07.43', '03.02.2009', '05.2.09']
for element in dates_list_modified:
    split_string = element.split(".")
    if len(split_string[0]) == 1:
        new_list = ["0", split_string[0]]
        split_string[0] = "".join(new_list)
    if len(split_string[1]) == 1:
        new_list = ["0", split_string[1]]
        split_string[1] = "".join(new_list)
    if len(split_string[2]) == 2:
        if split_string[2] == YEAR[2:4]:
            new_list = ["20", split_string[2]]
            split_string[2] = "".join(new_list)
        else:
            new_list = ["19", split_string[2]]
            split_string[2] = "".join(new_list)
    element = ".".join(split_string)
print(dates_list_modified)
```

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: Your [mre] is far from minimal.

Comment: Hey, guys! Thank you very much for your help. But one thing i still don't really understand. Why is it, that the programm knows what's up at the beginning of it, when "element.split" fetches and splits from list, and "element" at the end of the loop, still in scope of it, doesn't get the data in the list. And the article of Ned Batchelder (very interesting by the way), doesn't explain this case in my eyes. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to write the new string back to the list by keeping track of the index:

```py
dates_list_modified = ['7.2.2009', '03.08.2023', '18.07.43', '03.02.2009', '05.2.09']
for index,element in enumerate(dates_list_modified):
    split_string = element.split(".")
    if len(split_string[0]) == 1:
        new_list = ["0", split_string[0]]
        split_string[0] = "".join(new_list)
    if len(split_string[1]) == 1:
        new_list = ["0", split_string[1]]
        split_string[1] = "".join(new_list)
    if len(split_string[2]) == 2:
        if split_string[2] == YEAR[2:4]:
            new_list = ["20", split_string[2]]
            split_string[2] = "".join(new_list)
        else:
            new_list = ["19", split_string[2]]
            split_string[2] = "".join(new_list)
    dates_list_modified[index] = ".".join(split_string)
print(dates_list_modified)
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
dates_list_modified = ['7.2.2009', '03.08.2023', '18.07.43', '03.02.2009', '05.2.09']
new_dates_list = []

for element in dates_list_modified:
    split_string = element.split(".")
    
    if len(split_string[0]) == 1:
        new_list = ["0", split_string[0]]
        split_string[0] = "".join(new_list)
    if len(split_string[1]) == 1:
        new_list = ["0", split_string[1]]
        split_string[1] = "".join(new_list)
    if len(split_string[2]) == 2:
        if split_string[2] == split_string[2][2:4]:
            new_list = ["20", split_string[2]]
            split_string[2] = "".join(new_list)
        else:
            new_list = ["19", split_string[2]]
            split_string[2] = "".join(new_list)
    
    new_dates_list.append(".".join(split_string))

print(new_dates_list)
```